# How to export multiple artboards coordinates (x y) to file?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-scripting, script

I have an Illustrator file with several artboards as attached.

In particular I have an artboard that contains all the others. 
The other artboards concern the individual objects to be exported.

I need to export the coordinates of the artboards containing the objects to a file (csv, txt, etc.). The origin 0,0 is set in the top left vertex of the artboard that contains them all.

I think it's a pretty simple thing to do with a script but I don't know where to start.

Does anyone have suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Download the  javascript reference and look up what artboard object has in it.

Answer (score 0):

I did some tests and I think I found a solution with the following script. 
Essentially I did a loop to retrieve the values ​​from the artboardRect property and save them in csv.

I hope it's useful to someone :)

```
alert ('Artboard num: '+app.activeDocument.artboards.length);

//Open a new text file.
var myTextFile = File.saveDialog("Save CSV As", undefined);
//If the user clicked the Cancel button, the result is null.
if(myTextFile != null){
  //Open the file with write access.
  myTextFile.open("w");
  myTextFile.writeln('Artboard, x, y\n');

  for (i=0; i<app.activeDocument.artboards.length; i++) {
    // .. using each by indexed number
    // .. and what you want to know is
    // "artboardRect: Size and position of artboard"
    r = app.activeDocument.artboards[i].artboardRect;
    n = app.activeDocument.artboards[i].name;
    // now r holds the coordinates:
    //alert ('name:'+n+'\n x:'+r[0]+'\n y:'+ Math.abs(r[1]));
    myTextFile.writeln(n+','+r[0]+','+Math.abs(r[1])+'\n');
  }

  myTextFile.write("\r");
  myTextFile.close();
}
```